# How do I get pixels from Canvas created by js-dosbox

Tags: javascript, dosbox

I have worked through the dosbox Div to find the canvas, but once I have found the node holding the canvas how can I reference it?

Getting the context of dbGranChild[0] just results in an error..

Im trying to build an array of the pixels that make up the dosbox window, so thought using the canvas get image and looping through as frames change would be one way. If there is a better way altogether than my above attempt happy to take that as an answer.

Code: http://plnkr.co/edit/MC1n9HfwWcqXlAk95XCO?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>js-dos api</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        .dosbox-container { width: 640px; height: 400px; }
        .dosbox-container > .dosbox-overlay { background: url(https://js-dos.com/cdn/digger.png); }
        .dosbox-start { font-size: 35px !important; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dosbox"></div>
        <br/>
        <button onclick="dosbox.requestFullScreen();">Make fullscreen</button>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js-dos.com/cdn/js-dos-api.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var dosbox = new Dosbox({
            id: "dosbox",
            onload: function (dosbox) {
            dosbox.run("https://js-dos.com/cdn/digger.zip", "./DIGGER.COM");
            },
            onrun: function (dosbox, app) {
            console.log("App '" + app + "' is runned");
            }
        });
        var dosboxId = document.getElementById('dosbox');
        dbChild = dosboxId.childNodes;
        dbGranChild = dbChild[0].childNodes;
        console.log(dbGranChild[0])

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the w3Schools [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp).

First, you need to use a `<canvas>` tag instead of a `<div>`.

That is, replace this:

```
<div id="dosbox"></div>
```

with something like this:

```
<canvas id="dosbox" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>`
```

Second, replace this code:

```
var dosboxId = document.getElementById('dosbox');
dbChild = dosboxId.childNodes;
dbGranChild = dbChild[0].childNodes;
console.log(dbGranChild[0])
```

With something like this:

```
var c = document.getElementById("dosbox");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.stroke();
```